# Which Demo Weapons count for the Left 4 Heads Achievement

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2

The Left 4 Heads achievement is to behead 4 people in 10 seconds. Which of the demo melee weapons count as beheading as per the achievement?

I know that obviously the Eyelander will, since it debuted with the achievement in the first place, but what about the new swords since? The axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All weapons that can decapitate will work with the achievement, including those which do not buff you based on how many heads you've taken in a life. That means all these:

- Eyelander
- Scotsman's Skullcutter
- Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker
- Claidheamh Mòr
- Half-Zatoichi

It *does* make things easier if you equip weapons that help you run faster, like the Eyelander or the HHHH. I wouldn't use the Skullcutter for it.

Obviously, you have to be a Demoman to get the achievement using the Half-Zatoichi; it won't count if you're a Soldier.

Comment: The Headtaker is the exact same weapon as the Eyelander.

Comment: @Arda Xi: Except without the taunt, sadly :(

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro The taunt doesn't really work for an axe though.

Comment: @Arda Xi: That's true...

Comment: Ironically, I got this achievement today without even trying, using the (relatively) generic Eyelander. Yay for Degroot Keep?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer +1 Degroot keep is the way to go for this achievement, now that it exists :).   In the early days it was a bit more difficult (although still not too terrible).

Comment: For future reference, the Persian Persuader also decapitates enemies.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Obtaining Demoman Achievements](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Obtaining_Demoman_achievements) page on the [official TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com):

> ### Left 4 Heads
>
> Decapitate 4 players with only 10 seconds between each kill.
>
> **Difficulty:** Hard
>   **How to obtain:** Equip the [Eyelander](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Eyelander), [Scotsman's Skullcutter](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scotsman%27s_Skullcutter), [Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Horseless_Headless_Horsemann%27s_Headtaker), [Claidheamh Mòr](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Claidheamh_M%C3%B2r), or [Half-Zatoichi](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Half-Zatoichi) and engage multiple enemies at close range. Pair your melee weapon with the [Chargin’ Targe](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Chargin%E2%80%99_Targe) in order to reach new targets before the ten seconds expire.

Comment: Care to expand? A link to the main page of the wiki is hardly qualitative.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Updated my answer.